# ember.js: my bindings are working in a context but not in another

Tags: ember.js

I have a chunk of code that is working in a very simple environment:

here is my `index.hbl`

```
{{view App.SearchInvoicableProductFormView}}
```

here is my view

```
App.SearchInvoicableProductFormView = Em.View.extend
  templateName: 'search_invoicable_product_form'
  invoicableSearch: "Search..."
```

here is my template `search_invoicable_product.hbl`:

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="invoicableSearch" size="8"}}<br />
{{#each invoicable in results}}
{{invoicable.name}}<br />
{{/each}}
```

and here is my controller:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend
  invoicableSearch: "Cerca..."

  results: (->
    if @get("invoicableSearch").length > 3
      App.Invoicable.find(q: @get("invoicableSearch"))
  ).property("invoicableSearch")
```

In this context everything is working fine. When i type something into my text field the search is performed

---

While in this context bindings do not work:

I'm at path: `invoices/new`

here is my router:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource "invoices", ->
    @route 'new'
```

here are my routes:

```
App.InvoicesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> App.Invoice.find()

App.InvoicesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    App.Invoice.createRecord()
```

here is my controller:

```
App.InvoicesNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend 
  invoicableSearch: "Search..."

  results: (->
    if @get("invoicableSearch").length > 3
      App.Invoicable.find(q: @get("invoicableSearch"))
  ).property("invoicableSearch")
```

here are my views:

```
App.InvoiceRowFormView = Em.View.extend
  templateName: "invoices/invoice_row_form"

App.SearchInvoicableProductFormView = Em.View.extend
  templateName: 'invoices/search_invoicable_product_form'
```

ans here are my TEMPLATES:

invoices.hbl

```
{{#each controller}}
...
{{/each}}
{{outlet}}
```

invoice.hbl

```
<form>
{{partial 'invoices/form'}}
</form>
```

invoices/form.hbl

```
...form for invoice...
{{partial 'invoices/invoice_rows'}}
```

invoices/invoice_rows.hbl

```
{{#each invoiceRows}}
{{view App.InvoiceRowFormView}}
{{/each}}
```

invoices/invoice_row_form.hbl

```
...
{{view App.SearchInvoicableProductFormView}}
...
```

invoices/search_invoicable_product_form.hbl

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="invoicableSearch" size="8"}}<br />
{{#each invoicable in results}}
{{invoicable.name}}<br />
{{/each}}
```

In conclusion: I just moved the same code in a deeper position into my application. Code of invoices/search_invoicable_product_form.hbl is not changed, like the code into App.InvoicesNewController, that is the same of the code inside IndexController.

But I lost my bindings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass along the controller to each of these views, I think. Try this:

```
{{#each invoiceRows}}
  {{view App.InvoiceRowFormView controllerBinding="this"}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: something has changed. I can see "Search..." placeholder in my search box, binding fires once when i create the html chunk, but does not fire when i change the attribute

Comment: it works! the problem was that some chunks of html were created and then moved in another place inside the dom. I think ember does not like it!